# DirectShowNet - Error when recreating graph for webcam after unplug/replug back in

Tags: c#, com, webcam, directshow, directshow.net

I've spent almost 4 hours trying to figure out a solution for this issue. Basically, I am writing an application in C# using [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) that shows video from a webcam, allows you to take snapshots, and change resolution of the webcam. I have a device manager that detects when a webcam is unplugged, then replugged back in. However, I'm having difficultly recreating the graph after the device has been plugged back in.

The first thing I do is create the FilterGraph object and cast it to a IFilterGraph3. Then, I make this call:

```
graphBuilder.AddSourceFilterForMoniker(deviceMoniker, null, deviceName, out sourceFilter)
```

This call works when you initially launch the application, and even if you Dispose of the graph and create a new one. However, the only time is doesn't work is when trying to create the graph after the device is plugged back in.

On one machine (Win8 x64), I am receiving this error:

```
REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG - 0x80040154 - Class not registered
```

On another machine (Win7 x64), I am receiving this error:

```
REGDB_E_IIDNOTREG - 0x80040155 - Interface not registered
```

I have tested both building this code as **Any CPU** and **x86**. Also, I have tested it on other machines, but independent of the OS, I still get the **Interface not registered** error. I have tried using both a [Logitech C920](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920) and a [Microsoft LifeCam Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/lifecam-studio). Both result in the same error. I have also tried the alternative, using the IMoniker method:

```
deviceMoniker.BindToObject(null, null, ref baseFilterId, out source);
```

Same error occurs. I feel like there may be something that is lingering after the device is disconnected that I am not cleaning up to allow the graph to grab the source (webcam filter) properly. Any ideas would be appreciated.

General HRESULT error codes can be found here: [COM Error Codes (Generic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, I just woke up one morning, got to work, and stared at the code and went, "Wait, I know why this isn't working...". It is a **threading issue**. The initial graphs I was creating were on a different thread than the graphs I was trying to create later. That's why it only happens when I **recreate** the graphs.

I was also having a problem with `IVideoWindow's put_Owner` method when the device is plugged in **after the application has already started**. In this case, the device wasn't unplugged while executing, and put_Owner would freeze/deadlock trying to that method.

Overall, I have a thread that is detecting when a device is unplugged/plugged in using `DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice)`. So, when I go to create these graphs, they are not on the main UI thread where the other graphs were originally created. To solve this, I have my class that is handling the devices take in an `Action<Action> invoker` which allows you to provide a method wrapper. In this case, I pass it `Control.Invoke` of the WinForms form so that the calls on the device monitoring thread are wrapped by this invoker method within the UI thread. Completely solved my graph creation issues.

I am ***HIGHLY SURPRISED*** no one else ran into this before.  I couldn't find anyone else mentioning threading when discussing issues related to this error. Very strange.

Comment: Because threading would not be an issue in C++ development and DirectShow. It's DirectShow.NET and less people hit it.